# Error al actualizar datos de usuario en mysql

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código para actualizar los datos del usuario. No se el motivo por el cual no me actualiza la información del usuario.

Este es el código:

```
   <?php
include 'include_sesions.php';

if (!empty($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user='$_POST[first_name]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (!empty($_POST['last_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql1 = "UPDATE usuario SET Apellido_user='$_POST[last_name]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql1);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (!empty($_POST['provincia'])) { // <= false
    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuario SET Provicncia_user='$_POST[provincia]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql2);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (!empty($_POST['cp'])) { // <= false
    $sql3 = "UPDATE usuario SET CP_user='$_POST[cp]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql3);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
$extensiones = array(0=>'image/jpg',1=>'image/jpeg',2=>'image/png');
$max_tamanyo = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

$ruta_fichero_origen = $_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
$ruta_nuevo_destino = '../img/Img_profile/' . $_FILES['imagen1']['name'];
if ( in_array($_FILES['imagen1']['type'], $extensiones) ) {
     if ( $_FILES['imagen1']['size']< $max_tamanyo ) {
         if($row['Img_user']!=NULL){
            unlink("../img/Img_profile/".$row['Img_user']);
         }
          if( move_uploaded_file ( $ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino ) ) {
               header('Location: panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario
          }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Te muestra algún mensaje?

Comment: Nada, es como si funcionara bien pero no lo hace

Comment: Puedes indicar que has intentado hacer para debugear el código?

Comment: He probado a jugar con las variables, asegurarme que no esten vacias. y pocas cosas mas.

Comment: Luego de cada $query asegúrate de ejecutar $conexion->query($query); aunque te recomiendo que cambies el nombre de $query a $sql.

Comment: En que punto del código ejecutas la consulta de UPDATE?

Comment: No veo que estés ejecutando ninguna de las consultas `UPDATE`

Comment: me da error de pagina.

Comment: Voto cierre por pregunta duplicada (y respondida): [Error de escritura en sentencia UPDATE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386157/error-de-escritura-en-sentencia-update)

Answer (score -1):

Si ejecutas este script:

```
<?php

echo "Hola '$foo'";
```

El resultado es:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: foo in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Hola ''
```

A no ser que estés cargando tu variable `$email` del fichero *include_sesions.php*, cada una de tus *queries* lanzará esta *notificación*, pero como PHP intenta no fallar las consultas se harán buscando un *string* vació en el campo `Correo_user`.

Supongamos que tienes la variable `$email`. El código se presta a poner *trazas* por "todas partes"... Comprueba cada query para ver que esta bien formada, así también sabes si en principio se van a ejecutar. Por ejemplo:

```
if (!empty($_POST['provincia'])) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuario SET Provicncia_user='$_POST[provincia]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    var_dump($sql2); // TRACE:
    $conexion->query($sql2);
}
```

Una vez que funcione deberías:

- **Sanitizar las entradas de datos**. Meter directamente en BD las entradas del formulario ya era malo hace 10 años...
- **Agrupar las consultas de actualización**. Tu criterio de búsqueda es el mismo y realizar múltiples consultas tiene un coste.
- **Reorganizar el código**. Por lo menos mete la parte que guarda la imagen en una función que devuelva la ruta, *y supongo que quieres guardar esta en la tabla de usuarios*, te faltaría una última query en el código actual.

A parte, el código sólo produce una re-dirección en caso de guardarse la imagen... ¿tiene esto sentido?

Comment: Si, el usuario solo actualiza sus datos del perfil, los cambia y redirecciono a la pagina principal con los datos guardados.

Comment: @Christian_hidalgo tal como tienes planteado el código, si funcionará, sólo redirecciona en caso de guardarse la imagen.

Comment: pero yo voy a la base de datos para comprovar si se han guardado los datos y no lo hace