# Error de escritura en sentencia UPDATE

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código y no sé el porqué me da error. Es un pequeño formulario que actualiza los datos del usuario por POST.

El error está sí o sí en las siguientes lineas de código. La variable `$email` esta en el archivo `sesions.php`:

Código actualizado:

```
    <?php
include 'include_sesions.php';

if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "
        UPDATE usuario
        SET Nombre_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST["first_name"]) ."'
        WHERE Correo_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($email) ."'
    ";
    $result = mysqli->query($sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}/*
if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user= '$_POST[last_name]' where Correo_user='$email'"; 
    $conexion->query($sql1);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['provincia'])) { // <= false
    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuario SET Provicncia_user='$_POST[provincia]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql2);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['cp'])) { // <= false
    $sql3 = "UPDATE usuario SET CP_user='$_POST[cp]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql3);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
$extensiones = array(0=>'image/jpg',1=>'image/jpeg',2=>'image/png');
$max_tamanyo = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

$ruta_fichero_origen = $_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
$ruta_nuevo_destino = '../img/Img_profile/' . $_FILES['imagen1']['name'];
if ( in_array($_FILES['imagen1']['type'], $extensiones) ) {
     if ( $_FILES['imagen1']['size']< $max_tamanyo ) {
         if($row['Img_user']!=NULL){
            unlink("../img/Img_profile/".$row['Img_user']);
         }
          if( move_uploaded_file ( $ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino ) ) {
               header('Location: panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario
          }
     }
}*/
?>
```

He probado de todas las formas, con comillas simples, con una sola comilla, con puntos en las variables POST(."$_post[]".) Pero nada me resulta.

Éste es el formulario:

```
<div id="Profile">
                <div class="container bootstrap snippet">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10" style="color:black"><h1>Perfil usuario</h1></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" style="color:white">Perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" style="margin-left:1rem; color:white">Editar perfil</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                <hr>
                                  <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">  
                                              <label for="first_name" style="color:white"><h4>Nombre: </h4> <?php echo $row['Nombre_user']?></label> 
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="last_name" style="color:white"><h4>Apellidos: </h4> <?php echo $row['Apellido_user'] ?></label>
                                               
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email" style="color:white"><h4>Correo electrónico:</h4> <?php echo $row['Correo_user'] ?></label>
                                                                                      </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="locate" style="color:white"><h4>Provincia</h4> <?php echo $row['Provincia_user'] ?></label>
                                                                                      </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="cp" style="color:white"><h4>Código postal:</h4> <?php echo $row['CP_user'] ?></label>
                                                                                
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                </form>
                              <hr>
                             </div><!--/tab-pane-->
                             <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                                 <hr>
                                 <br>
                                  <form class="form" action="actualizar_formulario.php" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="first_name" style="color:white"><h4>Nombre</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" title="enter your first name if any.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">

                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="last_name" style="color:white"><h4>Apellidos</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Introduce tus dos apellidos" title="enter your last name if any.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email" style="color:white"><h4>Provincia</h4></label><br>
                                              <select name="provincia">
                                                    <option value="">- selecciona -</option>
                                                    <option value="15">A coru&#241;a</option>
                                                    <option value="1">&#193;lava</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Albacete</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Alicante</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Almer&#237;a</option>
                                                    <option value="33">Asturias</option>
                                                    <option value="5">&#193;vila</option>
                                                    <option value="6">Badajoz</option>
                                                    <option value="7">Baleares</option>
                                                    <option value="8">Barcelona</option>
                                                    <option value="9">Burgos</option>
                                                    <option value="10">C&#225;ceres</option>
                                                    <option value="11">C&#225;diz</option>
                                                    <option value="39">Cantabria</option>
                                                    <option value="12">Castell&#243;n</option>
                                                    <option value="51">Ceuta</option>
                                                    <option value="13">Ciudad Real</option>
                                                    <option value="14">C&#243;rdoba</option>
                                                    <option value="16">Cuenca</option>
                                                    <option value="99">Extranjero</option>
                                                    <option value="17">Girona</option>
                                                    <option value="18">Granada</option>
                                                    <option value="19">Guadalajara</option>
                                                    <option value="20">Guip&#250;zcoa</option>
                                                    <option value="21">Huelva</option>
                                                    <option value="22">Huesca</option>
                                                    <option value="23">Ja&#233;n</option>
                                                    <option value="26">La rioja</option>
                                                    <option value="35">Las palmas</option>
                                                    <option value="24">Le&#243;n</option>
                                                    <option value="25">Lleida</option>
                                                    <option value="27">Lugo</option>
                                                    <option value="28">Madrid</option>
                                                    <option value="29">M&#225;laga</option>
                                                    <option value="52">Melilla</option>
                                                    <option value="30">Murcia</option>
                                                    <option value="31">Navarra</option>
                                                    <option value="32">Ourense</option>
                                                    <option value="34">Palencia</option>
                                                    <option value="36">Pontevedra</option>
                                                    <option value="37">Salamanca</option>
                                                    <option value="38">Santa cruz de tenerife</option>
                                                    <option value="40">Segovia</option>
                                                    <option value="41">Sevilla</option>
                                                    <option value="42">Soria</option>
                                                    <option value="43">Tarragona</option>
                                                    <option value="44">Teruel</option>
                                                    <option value="45">Toledo</option>
                                                    <option value="46">Valencia</option>
                                                    <option value="47">Valladolid</option>
                                                    <option value="48">Vizcaya</option>
                                                    <option value="49">Zamora</option>
                                                    <option value="50">Zaragoza</option>
                                                </select>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="cp" style="color:white"><h4>Código postal</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp" placeholder="Introduce tu código postal" title="enter a location">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="img_profile" style="color:white"><h4>Cambiar imágen de perfil</h4></label><br>
                                              <input  style="color:white" type="file" class="text-center center-block file-upload"> 
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <br>
                                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Guardar</button>
                                                <button style="color:white" class="btn btn-lg" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Restablecer</button>
                                            </div>
                                      </div>
                                </form>
                             </div><!--/tab-pane-->
                             </div><!--/tab-pane-->
                          </div><!--/tab-content-->
                        </div><!--/col-9-->
                    </div><!--/row-->

          </div>
```

Y éste es el código completo de actualizar los datos:

```
<?php
include 'include_sesions.php';

if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user='$_POST[first_name]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user= '$_POST[last_name]' where Correo_user='$email'"; 
    $conexion->query($sql1);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['provincia'])) { // <= false
    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuario SET Provicncia_user='$_POST[provincia]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql2);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['cp'])) { // <= false
    $sql3 = "UPDATE usuario SET CP_user='$_POST[cp]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql3);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
$extensiones = array(0=>'image/jpg',1=>'image/jpeg',2=>'image/png');
$max_tamanyo = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

$ruta_fichero_origen = $_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
$ruta_nuevo_destino = '../img/Img_profile/' . $_FILES['imagen1']['name'];
if ( in_array($_FILES['imagen1']['type'], $extensiones) ) {
     if ( $_FILES['imagen1']['size']< $max_tamanyo ) {
         if($row['Img_user']!=NULL){
            unlink("../img/Img_profile/".$row['Img_user']);
         }
          if( move_uploaded_file ( $ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino ) ) {
               header('Location: panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario
          }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código HTML del formulario desde el que envías estos datos? ¿Podrías decirnos cómo obtienes `$email`? Además, debes hacer uso de [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) cada vez que quieras insertar cadenas que están fuera de tu control a una consulta SQL o bien usar consultas preparadas. La [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) es un problema serio que [debes tener siempre en cuenta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY).

Comment: Claro lo pongo ahora todo

Comment: Ya tengo detectado el error. Redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la forma en la que quieres introducir el valor de una matriz con índice de texto. Puedes ver en la documentación tanto la [sintaxis simple](http://php.net/es/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.simple) como la [sintaxis compleja](http://php.net/es/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Líneas, por ejemplo, en la que lo haces mal:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "
        UPDATE usuario
        SET Nombre_user='$_POST[first_name]'
        WHERE Correo_user='$email'
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
```

Estás haciendo un mal uso de las cadenas. Debería ser:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "
        UPDATE usuario
        SET Nombre_user='${_POST["first_name"]}'
        WHERE Correo_user='$email'
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
```

---

Además, he de advertirte que el código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string).

También estás mezclando las llamadas a procedimientos como `mysqli_query` con las llamadas orientadas a objetos como `mysqli::query()`.

Además, estás haciendo uso de `mysqli_query($sql)` sin proporcionar la conexión como primer parámetro.

Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "
        UPDATE usuario
        SET Nombre_user='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["first_name"]) ."'
        WHERE Correo_user='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $email) ."'
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
```

Nueva edición con el cambio de procedimientos a objetos:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "
        UPDATE usuario
        SET Nombre_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST["first_name"]) ."'
        WHERE Correo_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($email) ."'
    ";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    // Blindamos el código ante errores en la consulta
    if ($result === false) {
        die("Error SQL: " . htmlspecialchars($conexion->error));
    }
}
```

También sufres problemas de seguridad relacionados con [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

```
<h4>Correo electrónico:</h4> <?php echo $row['Correo_user'] ?></label>
```

Deberías hacer uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para evitar estos problemas.

Por ejemplo, esa línea quedaría así:

```
<h4>Correo electrónico:</h4><?= htmlspecialchars($row['Correo_user']) ?></label>
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, he cambiado el código para hacer una prueba rapida, pero el error persiste.

Comment: ¿Te da algún mensaje de error? ¿Cómo has dejado el código?

Comment: Lo acabo de actualizar, he puesto la sentencia que me has pasado y he comentado el resto para que no de problemas.

Comment: Antes de esa edición usabas `mysqli_query()`. ¿Cómo estableces la conexión? ¿Con `new mysqli()` o con `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: utilizo new mysqli()

Comment: Vale, entonces otro error que estás cometiendo es mezclar las llamadas por procedimientos y las orientadas a objetos. Debes cambiar todos los `$conexion->query()` por lo que te voy a poner en mi respuesta.

Comment: Editado. Prueba, por favor, la última edición.

Comment: Debido a los problemas de comunicación, por favor, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112463/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-christian-hidalgo).